# How do you test response contains string in Inertia unit tests?

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

I am using Inertia and would like to run some tests to check whether the response contains a certain string.

```
->assertInertia(
            fn (AssertableInertia $page) => $page->component('UsersPage')->has('profile')->dd('profile.0.buttons')
        );
```

so the above works and i can dump the profile.0.buttons and see the string i want to check for, but how do i automatically test that this string exists? normal unit tests, i'd use assertSee. whereContains also doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I think that [Inertia page about testing](https://inertiajs.com/testing) has done a great job in summing the testing option for Laravel/Inertia.

Endpoint tests (assertInertia) are feature tests, and you can use them to check if a controller is sending the right components and data to Inertia.

Your question is going more in the direction of "Client-side unit tests" e.g. Jest, where you can send some data to React/Vue component and see how that data has been rendered.

There are "End-to-end tests": Cypress is great but lacks nice integration with setting up Laravel enviroment and seeders in test.

That leave us with [Laravel Dusk](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/dusk). I love this tool because it give us best of both worlds (backend and frontend).
You can set up your test with seeders or Model factories, and in the same test you can fire up virtual browser and see how Inertia rendered page. Best thing is that you can use helpers for typing and clicking so you can realy test your app and how it behaves.