# PHPunit - Ineria assertSee a string does exist

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, inertiajs

Similar to this question: [How do you test response contains string in Inertia unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72969343/how-do-you-test-response-contains-string-in-inertia-unit-tests)

How can I test if a string exists when using Laravel 9, Vue 3, and inertia?

My code:

```
public function test_footer_is_loading()
{
    $user = User::factory()->create();

    $this
        ->actingAs($user)
        ->get(route('home'))
        ->assertInertia(fn (Assert $assert) => $assert
            ->has('all rights reserved')
        );
    // $response->assertSee('all rights reserved');
}
```

I think `has` looks for a property or variable?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer is NO you can't check if there's a string. But this page is all you need to know everything about testing with Ineria:
https://github.com/claudiodekker/inertia-laravel-testing/blob/8c8191b2b910ebdd4979911c9fbae60a188a85b4/README.md
It's a package that is merged to Inertia now